# How to record audio and video using JAVASCRIPT ? (REACT JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, video, web-mediarecorder

I have tried but there is an error **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stop')"**
I am calling function on button click
here is function  as well :)

```
const getAudio= async ()=>{

         let device = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
         let chunks = [];
         let recorder;
         device.then(stream => {
             recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
             recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
                 chunks.push(e.data);
                 if (recorder.state === 'inactive') {
                     this.blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: 'audio/webm'});
                     let testAudioRecord  = URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
                     console.log(testAudioRecord)
                 }
             }
             recorder.start(1000);
         });
         setTimeout(() => {
             recorder.stop();     //   Cannot read ('stop') =error
         }, 2000)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I spot a bit of a mixup between using async with await, and the .then promise handling.

Since you are using an async function, lets refactor to `try...catch` with await to wait for the promoise to resolve.

```
  const getAudio = async () => {
    let chunks = [];
    let recorder;

    try {
      //wait for the stream promise to resolve
      let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
        chunks.push(e.data);
        if (recorder.state === "inactive") {
          this.blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/webm" });
          let testAudioRecord = URL.createObjectURL(this.blob);
          console.log(testAudioRecord);
        }
      };
      recorder.start(1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
        recorder.stop();
      }, 2000);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error getting stream", e);
    }
  };
```

There are better ways to construct the code, but this should get your function working.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-worker-bwh8j?file=/src/App.js) with your function and a playback option

Here is another audio [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/audio-experiments-w7yz8?file=/src/App.js:2028-2093)